# SignalR Connection interrupted

Tags: signalr

I have a signalR connection in a first page.

```
<script>
var online = $.connection.onlineHub;

online.client.aMessage = function () {

};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    online.server.send();
});
</script>
```

The connection interrupt when i go to another page. Is there way this not happen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to keep a SignalR connection open if your navigating away from the page responsible for initiating the connection.

One way you could potentially work around this issue is by creating a [Single-Page Application or SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).